# "on to which" and "on which" difference in this context

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I came across this definition:

"the board or bench on to which a person is strapped during the process of waterboarding."

what difference does that makes inmeaning if a remove the "to" from this sentence:

"the board or bench on which a person is strapped during the process of waterboarding."

I can't see any differene.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct and for intents and purposes interchangeable in your examples. There is however a very slight difference in the sense that **on** denotes *position* while **onto** denotes *movement plus position*.

You can observe the same difference in the following pair:

*He put his hand in his pocket.

He put his hand into his pocket.*

I think "on which" is (much) more common that "onto which". Here are some Google search results:

"on which it is strapped": 122000
"onto which it is strapped": 1

And for the examples I gave above, here is an Ngram: ([link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=put%20it%20in%20his%20pocket%2Cput%20it%20into%20his%20pocket&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cput%20it%20in%20his%20pocket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20it%20into%20his%20pocket%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cput%20it%20in%20his%20pocket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20it%20into%20his%20pocket%3B%2Cc0))

[image]

And as @JackO'Flaherty has mentioned in his comment:

> You could actually say "the board **to** which a person is strapped".

In fact, if we search for "he" instead of "it" in the Google search above:

"onto which he is strapped": 0
"on which he is strapped": 5
"to which he is strapped": 127000

And here is a second Ngram: ([link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=onto%20which%20he%20is%20strapped%2Con%20which%20he%20is%20strapped%2Cto%20which%20he%20is%20strapped&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cto%20which%20he%20is%20strapped%3B%2Cc0))

[image]

Comment: what is the difference between: "He put his hand in his pocket." and "He put his hand into his pocket." exactly?

Comment: regarding: "the board or bench on to which a person is strapped during the process of waterboarding" if you strapp someone on a board or bench you are logically talking strapp on make no sense denote movement in this case, don't you agree??

Comment: You could actually say "the board **to** which a person is strapped".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty. You are right.