# Why use "on to which" instead of just "on which"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I've written this post:

["on to which" and "on which" difference in this context](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/314602/on-to-which-and-on-which-difference-in-this-context)

and regarding this definition: "the board or bench on to which a person is strapped during the process of waterboarding."

but still quite don't understand the reason to choose to use "on to which" instead of just using "on which"
as I learned "on to" denotes movement, But I belive makes no sense to denote movement if you just strap someone/something on a board/bech right? you just "strap on" in this case right?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that *on* would be acceptable here, but *onto* (I would write it as one word) is more precise.

The "movement" implied by *onto* does not have to be literal movement, but can indicate an increased connection: *strap onto*, *hold onto*, *plug into* are examples where there may be no significant movement, but something ends up more closely connected.

"On which the person is strapped" *could* mean that the person is on the board and being strapped to something else - not a likely interpretation in this case, I admit; but that is why I describe it as less precise.

Comment: @olin Fine, I got it. in case of: "He put his hand in his pocket." and "He put his hand into his pocket" differences,  the latter implies movement right? literal movement, right?

Comment: Well, sort of. But _put_ **requires** a location argument, and necessarily implies movement, so we mostly use simple prepositions (_in_, _on_, _under_, _against_ etc) rather than _into_ or _onto_. _He put his hand into his pocket_ is less common, and generally implies purpose: we wouldn't say _He put his hands into his pockets_ to mean he was just standing casually: that would suggest that he was going to pull something particular out of his pockets.